# Testing an Windows Application using Mouse Click and Screen Capture

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automated-tests, mouseevent

I would like to use python to control a windows application. I would like to click on certain button on a application using Python. Also, I would like to verify the reaction to click as expected --for example:pop up happens when it is expected.  So far I have been reading PyAutoGUI to use it to automate click function( as well as to locate the button to click). To check for reaction, I have two option -

1) Do the Image Comparison between what shows up on  application window and images of what is expected for asserting test pass/fail. But the problem is all text will be considered as image in comparison so I don't know how accurate will that be.

2) Use OCR to convert all readable text from screenshot of software(being tested) and compare text to text. The problem with this approach is I won't be able to check plots, bar.

I have never done testing of software application so I appreciate any insights.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried?

Comment: I have been reading documentation on PyAutoGUI. I don't think reference coordinate are relative to application windows but rather the screen which will cause issue for me. My goal here is test automation. Moreover, I want to be sure it will work with windows locked.